# How to exit function if user cancels or doesn't enter anything into inputbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that inserts text into a newly inserted row after it asks for the user to input text into an InputBox. The issue I have is that if the user selects cancel on the InputBox, the code will still run and it will insert a new row and write FALSE into column E. If nothing is entered and I press OK, then it will exit the function correctly. However, how do I also make it so that it exits the function when the user presses cancel?

```
Public Function ContactAdd() As Long
Dim cF As Range
Dim Response As String

With Worksheets("Database").Range("B:B")
'Find the cell in column B containing value in combobox
Set cF = .Find(What:=Worksheets("Database").ComboBox1, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

'If cell in column B is found
If Not cF Is Nothing Then
    'Open inputbox
    Response = Application.InputBox("Enter contact name")
    'If inputbox is cancelled, exit function
    If Response = "" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid - Exiting"
        Exit Function
    Else
    'If entry to inputbox is made, insert row below the combobox value that was found and paste response into column E of the row that was inserted
    cF.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    ContactAdd = cF.Offset(1, 0).Row
    Worksheets("Database").Cells(ContactAdd, 5).Value = Response
    End If
    Exit Function
End If
End With

ContactAdd = 0
End Function

Private Sub InsertContact1_Click()
'Execute ContactAdd function when button is clicked
ContactAdd
End Sub
```

This part of my code is therefore incorrect and I'm not sure why... I've tried using vbNullString instead of "" as well which didn't help.

```
    If Response = "" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid - Exiting"
        Exit Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is, that Application.InputBox is not the same as the "normal" InputBox. So if you use:

```
Response = InputBox("Enter contact name")
'If inputbox is cancelled, exit function
If Response = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid - Exiting"
    Exit Function
End If
```

it would work. If you want to use Application.InputBox instead, you have to change the IF statement to:

```
If Response = False Then
```

but in that case you have to define Response as Variant.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.InputBox()` returns `False` on Cancel, while `InputBox()` returns `""`. See the online help.

Try this in the Immediate window:

```
? (InputBox("Click cancel") = "")

? (Application.InputBox("Click cancel") = False)
```

Both return True on Cancel.